# Can't get Jest expo app to work with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation, expo, react-test-renderer

I am trying to snapshot test with Jest, Expo, React Navigation and my whole app uses hooks only. I'd like to eventually make these into e2e tests where Jest clicks through and snapshot tests everything but I can't even get react navigation to render. My snapshot after the expo loader always shows "null." I followed the basic example from the tabs starter that comes with `expo init` but the way it outlines how to setup the mocks simply doesn't work for my app. I've tried all sorts of things but nothing works.

App.tsx

```js
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
import { Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import { useScreens } from 'react-native-screens';
import { Provider as RxProvider } from 'reactive-react-redux';
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import SnackBar from './components/UI/Snackbar';
import { socketMiddleware } from './lib/socketMiddleware';
import SwitchNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer';
import { theme } from './Theme';

const middleware = [thunk, socketMiddleware()];
const composeEnhancers = (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
export const store = createStore<iAppState, any, any, any>(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

// Must be called prior to navigation stack rendering
useScreens();

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Require cycle:']);

const App = (props) => {
  const [isLoadingComplete, setLoadingComplete] = useState(false);

  if (!isLoadingComplete && !props.skipLoadingScreen) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={loadResourcesAsync}
        onError={handleLoadingError}
        onFinish={() => handleFinishLoading(setLoadingComplete)}
      />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <RxProvider store={store}>
        <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
          <SwitchNavigator />
          <SnackBar />
        </PaperProvider>
      </RxProvider>
    );
  }
};

const loadResourcesAsync = async () => {
  await Promise.all([
    Asset.loadAsync([
      //nothing
    ]),
    Font.loadAsync({
      ...Ionicons.font,
      TitilliumText250: require('./assets/fonts/TitilliumText22L-250wt.otf'),
      TitilliumText800: require('./assets/fonts/TitilliumText22L-800wt.otf')
    })
  ]);
};

const handleLoadingError = (error: Error) => {
  console.warn(error);
};

const handleFinishLoading = (setLoadingComplete) => {
  setLoadingComplete(true);
};

export default App;
```

App.test.tsx:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import NavigationTestUtils from 'react-navigation/NavigationTestUtils';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import App from './App';
import { theme } from './Theme';

jest.mock('expo', () => ({
  AppLoading: 'AppLoading'
}));
jest.mock('react-native-screens');
jest.mock('react-native-paper');
jest.mock('redux');
jest.mock('reactive-react-redux');
jest.mock('./navigation/AppNavigator', () => 'SwitchNavigator');

describe('App', () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();

  beforeEach(() => {
    NavigationTestUtils.resetInternalState();
  });

  // success
  it(`renders the loading screen`, () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<App />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  // this snapshot is always null
  it(`renders the root without loading screen`, () => {
    const tree = renderer
      .create(
        <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
          <App skipLoadingScreen></App>
        </PaperProvider>
      )
      .toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

/navigation/AppNavigator.tsx:

```js
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import LoginStack from './LoginStack';
import TabStack from './TabStack';

/** The most root navigator which allocates to the others. */
const SwitchNavigator = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      LoginStack: LoginStack,
      TabStack: TabStack
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'LoginStack'
    }
  )
);

export default SwitchNavigator;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and found a fix via: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/7155#issuecomment-592681861

Seems like the act() worked magically for me to stop it from returning null (not sure how)

Update your test to use it like this:

```
import { act, create } from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders the root without loading screen', () => {
    let tree;

    act(() => {
      tree = create(
        <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
          <App skipLoadingScreen></App>
        </PaperProvider>
      );
    });

    expect(tree.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

Note: When I changed how I was using the imports from 'react-test-renderer' my tests couldn't find act() as a function, a simple re-install of npm packages solved this problem!